# Exception Value: (Cannot resolve keyword) In Django

Tags: python, django, django-3.0

I'm about to make a simple webshop, and are currently working on my add to cart button.

When I click the add to cart button right now, it returns an error as follows:

```
FieldError at /add-to-cart/box-1/

Exception Value:    
Cannot resolve keyword 'ordered' into field. Choices are: box, box_id, id, order, quantity, title
```

#### Related Code

**views.py:**

```
def add_to_cart(request, slug):
    # Get the item from the slug via get_object_or_404 method
    box = get_object_or_404(Box, slug=slug)
    # Check if the user have an order
    order_box = OrderBox.objects.create(box=box)
    order_qs = OrderBox.objects.filter(user=request.user, ordered=False)

    if order_qs.exists():
        order = order_qs[0]
        # Check if order item is in the order
        if order.box.filter(box__slug=box.slug).exists():
            order_box.quantity += 1
            order_box.save()
    else:
        ordered_date = timezone.now()
        order = Order.objects.create(user=request.user, ordered_date=ordered_date)
        order.items.add(order_box)

    return redirect('webshop:shop-box', slug=slug)
```

**models.py**

```
class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderBox)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ordered_date = models.DateTimeField()
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

I've been searching around, and can find different questions on this topic, however I can't understand what the issue is. 
I'd much appreciate some help to figure out where I've mistaken, thank you!

Comment: The issue is here: `OrderBox.objects.filter(user=request.user, ordered=False)`. `ordered` is not a valid keyword argument. You have an `ordered` field on your `Order` model, but not on your `OrderBox` model, so it's invalid when querying for `OrderBox`es.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `OrderBox` does not have a field called `ordered` (or `user` for that matter), your `Order` model does. So without knowing too much about your project, you either need to create a queryset for your `Order` model instead of `OrderBox` or filter your `OrderBox` queryset by their related `Order` models (if they are related, it appears so from the available fields listed in the error message). If this is the case, you could 
try `OrderBox.objects.filter(order__user=request.user, order__ordered=False)`